# How to let xcode project output Unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I know android project can output in jar file and use in Unity.
I have done the `xcode` project and I want to output in Unity.'
HOW can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: Output as in print in console? Use Debug.Login.  if u mean to create a plug in with objective c cider then it is a bit longer.

Comment: not for console, I want  to make xcode project become a file and put the file in Uunity .Just like the android project can output Jar.  file.

Comment: Could be this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/000-Introduction/Introduction.html